# Finite Group problem

Tags: group-theory

Show that if $G$ is a finite group and $N$ is a subgroup of index 2, then
for elements a and b of G, the product ab is an element of $N$ if and only
if either both of a and b are in N or neither of a and b is in $N$.

This problem seems fairly straightforward, but I'm confused on how I start this problem, or where to go with it.

Comment: consider the homomorphism from $G$ onto $G/N$; $G/N$ has order $2$

Comment: What are the cosets of $N$ in $G$?

Comment: Well since we have two of them, can they be anything?

Comment: They are $N$ and $G\setminus N$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index of the subgroup $N$ is the number of (left or right) cosets of $N$ in $G$ (it doesn't matter if left or right because $N$ is normal). It is well known that the cosets of a normal subgroup are the equivalence classes of the equivalence relation given by $x\sim y$ iff $x*y^{-1}\in N$. Then there are just two equivalence classes, and one of them has to be $N$, since it corresponds to the left coset $xN$ for any $x\in N$ (because $N$ is a group). Since equivalence classes are disjoint, and their union is the total set, the other equivalence class has to be $G\setminus N$.

If $a*b\in N$: if $a\in N$ then $a^{-1}\in N$ (since $N$ is a group), so $b=a^{-1}*(a*b)\in N$; if $b\in N$ then $b^{-1}\in N$ (same reason), so $a=(a*b)*b^{-1}\in N$. Then either both $a,b\in N$, or neither of them is.

If both $a,b\in N$ or neither of them is: if both $a,b\in N$ then $a*b\in N$, since $N$ is a group; if neither $a$ nor $b$ is in $N$ then $b^{-1}$ can't be in $N$, since then $b$ should be too, so both $a$ and $b^{-1}$ are in $G\setminus N$, and consequently they belong to the same equivalence class, thus $a*b=a*(b^{-1})^{-1}\in N$.

Note that the fact that the index is 2 and $N$ is normal (so we could we use the machinery of equivalence classes) is only needed in the last part.

Comment: This makes sense however in the first half of the proof, how does it show that either both or neither of them are in N. I see that you showed if b $\in N$ then we have a $\in N$, and vice versa, but how does that cover that neither one of them would be in N

Comment: If $b$ isn't in $N$ then $a$ can't be, since otherwise we have shown that $b$ should be too (contradiction; we just assumed the converse). The same goes for assuming $a\notin N$.

Comment: Gotcha, maybe I missed something more, but you start the second paragraph off by assuming that $a*b \in N$ but then why do you go into those subcases for if $a\in N$ and the same thing for b, is this how these or statement proofs usually go?

Comment: Because we don't know a priori what's the situation for $a$ and $b$. The best thing we can do there is to assume one subcase by one as you say, so we consider all situations. This is called proof by exhaustion (by cases); and yes, it's a pretty common line (but not the only one) when proving some statements in mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

If both $a, b$ are in $N,$ being a subgroup it also contain the product $ab$ (and all possible combinations together with inverses).

Assume neither $a$ nor $b$ are in $N.$ Then clearly $a^{-1}\notin N.$ Consider their images under the canonical homomorphism $G\to G/N$ that maps $g\mapsto gN.$ Since $N$ if of index $2,$ the latter group has only two distinct elements (in fact isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}=(\{0, 1\}, +_2)$ ), namely, $N, a^{-1}N=bN.$ Hence multiplying both sides by $a$ we get $abN=N$ and it implies $ab\in N.$

Conversely, consider the case $a\in N,$ but $b\notin N.$ If $ab\in N,$ then $a^{-1}(ab)=b\in N$ gives a contradiction. Hence in this case $ab\notin N.$